# Ternary Operator in body tag for a GraphQL call

Tags: typescript, graphql

I make a graphql call with a file (formdata) or without a file (json). I want to use the same logic/function and just set the contentType and the content if we have a file or not. For example we have:

```
        method: 'POST',
        json: true,
        body: {
          type: ContentType.FormData,
          content: formData
        },
```

In pseudocode I wanted something like this, using a tenary operator:

```
        method: 'POST',
        json: true,
        body: {
      fileBlob? (
          type: ContentType.FormData,
          content: formData) :
           (
          type: ContentType.JsonData,
          content: jsonData)
        },
```

I have tried:

```
 body: {
          type: fileBlob ? ContentType.FormData : ContentType.FormData,
          content: fileBlob ? formData : jsonQuery
        }
```

But gives an error at `content`:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(init: CallInit): Promise<string | GqlResponse<myService> | null>', gave the following error.
    Type 'string | FormData' is not assignable to type 'FormData'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'FormData'.ts(2769)
```

Seems like TS thinks that there is a possibility that the `type` can resolve to string, and the `content` to formData? How to solve this, or any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your `jsonQuery` (which is a `string`) to `FormData`.

Also `fileBlob ? ContentType.FormData : ContentType.FormData` is not doing anything as both options are the same.